# Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in

Tags: twig, php

Вечер добрый всем!

Проблема такая, написал сайт на php + twig.
На денвере все прекрасно работает, стал переносить на хостинг получил вот такое:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in /var/www/an3611/data/boobaleh.ru/index.php on line 42
```

Подключал так:

```
 define( 'DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
 $twig = DIR.'/protected/lib/twig/Autoloader.php';
 require_once( $twig );

 Twig_Autoloader::register();

 $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( DIR.'/protected/templates/' ); // 42 строка
 $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array());
```

В чем же может быть проблема?

В общем решил проблему, отвечу тут, ибо в коменты уже не могу писать :(
**Проблема была** в имени папки, вместо `lib/twig` нужно `lib/Twig`
Или же можно было назвать класс иначе `twig_Loader_Filesystem`, а не так как был `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`.
Вот так-то ;-)
Спасибо всем кто помогал :)

Comment: Приведите значение:  

    DIR.'/protected/lib/twig/Autoloader.php'

Comment: <pre>/var/www/an3611/data/boobaleh.ru/protected/lib/twig/Autoloader.php</pre>

Comment: @andr-ik, у тебя бажина на сайте. Почисти все куки от своего сайта и посмотри на корзину

Comment: 1. Включены ли нотификации? Возможно, появляется нотификация, но вывод из в браузер отключен.  
2. Есть ли в файле

        DIR.'/protected/lib/twig/Autoloader.php'
    Класс.  

        Twig_Loader_Filesystem
?

Comment: 1. Эм, а что это? :(
2. Там стандартный класс (class Twig_Autoloader) для twig

Вообще в /protected/lib/twig/ ничего не менял, все отсюда
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Версия PHP на сервере: 5.2.17

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю :)

Comment: Изучите:  
http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php  
Сделайте вывод всех ошибок (потом отключите)- не безопасно на сервере их выводить.

Comment: в htaccess прописал
php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1

Comment: И ничего не выводится?

Comment: Борюсь с проблемой на новом домене: new.boobaleh.ru

Да, но у меня php 5.2.17
( Извините, не могу писать комментарии, почему-то )

Comment: > Twig needs at least PHP 5.2.4 to run

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation